# Measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measurable-sets

Suppose E and F are measurable sets of finite measures and E is contained in G contained in F. Prove G is measurable. I tried using the equivalence relation of measurable sets, but I see no reason why I should let epsylom

Answer (score 3):

This is not true.  For example, let $E=\emptyset$, $F=[0,1]$.  Then this would imply that every subset of $[0,1]$ is measurable, which is very false.

I think that this question is missing two conditions, namely that $\mu(E) = \mu(F)$, and $\mu$ is a complete measure (it is possible that you are specifically using the Lebesgue measure, but you didn't say so).  If you have these conditions the result is true.  A hint for proving this is to consider the set $F\setminus E$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Roger.  Fixed.